# SQL server password is null after azure import in local

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I exported my live database bacpac from azure and imported it in local system but the issue is my user table password is null when decrypted but it works fine in azure.I checked if there is any master key but it returned 0.Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Remove the master key object and the credential object from the bacpac. To learn how to do it or to explore another options, please visit [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/03/30/exported-database-from-azure-sql-failed-to-be-imported-to-azure-sql-or-to-local-sql-server/) article.

Hope this helps.